# How do I hide a option from a select element in jquery after change event?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to hide my default option with jQuery after the first option change is made, but I still see it.

```
$('#SpaceAccommodation').change(function () {
    $("#SpaceAccommodation").children("option[value^=default]").hide();
});

<select class="form-control" id="SpaceAccommodation" name="YogaSpaceAccommodation">
     <option value="default">0</option> 
     <option value="0">1-4</option>
     <option value="1">5-9</option>
     <option value="2">10-15</option>
     <option value="3">16-20</option>
     <option value="4">20+</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your code actually [works in Chrome/FF](http://jsfiddle.net/f28cbL0r/); however, you can't actually hide the `option` element in IE, you need to remove it. (this is one of many cross-browser inconsistencies..) Try `.remove()`.. and then prepend it back in if you ever want to show it again.

Comment: Side question--are you attaching the event listener onDOMReady? Try wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`

Comment: no I wasn't but removing it works! thanks!

Comment: Side question - why would I need to wrap it in onDOMReady, in this case?

Comment: It would entirely depend on where your `script` element is placed in the document and when it is executed. If the element `#SpaceAccommodation` doesn't exist when the jQuery is executed, the event listener isn't attached (unless you use event delegation). Clearly that wasn't your problem though.. I just wanted to throw that out there since it's a common problem on SO.

Comment: @Josh I'm using Rails and just ran across a JS problem which I had solved earlier today by moving all of the JS to the end of the template.  Is there any downside with this approach in general?

Comment: @steveklein No, there aren't really any downsides to that approach. That would just mean that everything above those `script` elements would load first (which is actually good in *most* cases). [Google actually recommends](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_javascript_last) moving the `script` elements to the bottom of the document.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Josh's comment will work in IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/w2Lu9pur/

```
$('#SpaceAccommodation').change(function () {
$("#SpaceAccommodation").children("option[value^=default]").remove();
});
```